# Objective-C Frameworks and namespace clashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-frameworks

We want to put 2 versions of our iOS app in the same bundle. This way our customers could revert to the legacy version after an update has been pushed. I had hoped to achieve this by building the current and previous versions into frameworks and calling the appropriate version after prompting the user.

As a test I've created two Frameworks, LibA & LibB, each containing class Thing.

The problem I'm encountering is this runtime warning...

`objc[21117]: Class Thing is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0E6374C5-52FB-421F-90D6-ADC9A4C22B5D/DualBootTestApp.app/Frameworks/LibA.framework/LibA (0x102b144b0) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0E6374C5-52FB-421F-90D6-ADC9A4C22B5D/DualBootTestApp.app/Frameworks/LibB.framework/LibB (0x102ba4460). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

In the real world, these Frameworks would be two versions of the same app, so 99% of the class names are going to be identical in each.

Each Framework does actually call its own version of Thing, but the runtime warning suggests to me I can't rely on that behaviour.

**Update**

I've just tried using a Cocoa Touch Static Library instead. With a static library I don't get the runtime warning, but the version of class Thing from LibB is always called, even when the call originates from LibA.

I'm starting to believe some kind of macro prefixing the objective c class names might be the only solution. Lots of shared code makes this a grim prospect.

Does anyone know a way I can hide the class names so only each Framework has visibility of its own classes?

Is there a better approach to adding two versions of an app into the same bundle? Is it even possible? Would there be issues with Appstore review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already made your classes into frameworks, congrats, you've done the hard part already. Bear in mind, however, that if much of your application code is in a framework, some things might not behave as expected. For instance, any code that ultimately calls `NSBundle.mainBundle` (eg `+[UIImage imageNamed:]`) is probably wrong, assuming you've versioned your assets as well.

But let's assume that you've successfully framework-ized your app versions.

You can't link against either framework if you want to choose one of them at runtime. Instead, you need to use `dlopen` and `NSClassFromString` or `dlsym` to reach an entry point.

Here's an example:

```
#import <dlfcn.h>
#import "HeaderWithEntryPointMethod.h"

void pickedAppVersion(int version) {
    NSString *frameworkName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AppV%d", version];
    NSString *frameworkExecutable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.framework/%@", frameworkName, frameworkName]; // this should traverse the symlink 
    NSString *frameworkPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] privateFrameworksPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:frameworkExecutable];
    void *frameworkHandle = dlopen(frameworkPath.UTF8String, RTLD_NOW);
    if (frameworkHandle != NULL) {
        Class EntryPointClass = NSClassFromString(@"EntryPoint");
        assert(EntryPointClass != Nil);
        [EntryPointClass entryMethod];
        // App framework should do everything from here
        if (dlclose(frameworkHandle) != 0) {
            NSLog(@"failed to close chosen app framework: %s", dlerror());
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"failed to open app framework: %@ because: %s", frameworkName, dlerror());
    }
}
```

As to exactly what `EntryPoint` is and `+entryMethod` does, that's up to you. If you need a C function entry point, use `dlsym` instead of `NSClassFromString`.

Re: App Store review: I imagine it might raise an eyebrow or two, but as long as you're allowing the user, especially the reviewer, to choose, there shouldn't be a problem. `dlopen` is commonly used to selectively load frameworks at runtime in order to streamline app launch and load features an application uses on demand.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks! I'll mark it accepted once I've had a chance to work through it. Also thanks for the warning about bundles, I had worked round that issue in my test cases, but weeding out bundle usage in my actual app may be a different story.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much! After implementing your answer, the only extra step was remove the frameworks from TARGETS>General>"Linked frameworks and libraries". I'd never heard of dlopen() before, I feel like I've taken my first step into a larger world!

Comment: You might also need to add a Copy Files build phase to copy them to the Frameworks folder, since the Linked Frameworks and Libraries build phase no longer will. You might not run into this until the next time you clean the project.

Comment: A small gotcha. I've made versions 1 & 2 of my app into frameworks. In my project I had a framework v1 target and a launcher app target, and copied in framework v2. The launcher picks the required framework at start-up. With this setup the warning, "Class XXX is implemented in both", reappears and the classes from framework v1 are always used. If I create a completely independent launcher project and copy in both frameworks, it runs fine. I don't fully understand this yet.

Comment: A larger gotcha is that after dlclose() is called on LibA, attempting to load LibB will result in the "Class XXX is implemented in both" warning. Meaning an app restart is required. Hopefully my boss/ AppStore reviewers will be ok with this.

Comment: You could possibly use `+[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier]`, `-load` and `-unload` instead of `dlopen/dlsym/dlclose`. I haven't tried to do anything with that for probably 18 years. Used to be it didn't work, but apparently bundle unloading actually works now and has for quite some time.

Comment: I've tried your idea out and the "Class XXX is implemented in both" warning reappears as soon as the 2nd bundle is loaded, even if the 1st bundle is unloaded beforehand. The link below states: "NSBundle correctly loads Objective-C symbols into the runtime system, but there is no way to unload Cocoa bundles once loaded due to a runtime limitation"

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/CFNSBundle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001270-BCIDBAEJ

I don't know if that documentation is out of date, but it supports what I'm seeing.

Comment: Ah, I guess I was interpreting the special note here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1412388-unload as meaning that ObjC code could be unloaded now and since 10.5. I guess not.

Comment: My app using dlopen and two frameworks was approved today! I left a note for the reviewer explaining that a restart was required after switching version. Thanks for your help!